# Passing a value from a javascript to another js file

Tags: javascript

My code is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeval() {
     $total = parseInt($("#small").val()) + parseInt($("#medium").val());
   }
</script>
```

How can I pass **'$total'** to another js file, say main.js.

Comment: Use return within your function and use changeval()

Answer (score 0):

Call `changeval` function from another file, save/use returned value.

```
function changeval() {
    return parseInt($("#small").val()) + parseInt($("#medium").val());
}
```

Or have one global variable save value inside the same variable and access it from another file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that $total is assigned to the global scope and make sure the script where you want to use it is below the script where you assign it.  Be careful about polluting the global scope too much because it can make code that is very tricky to debug and can cause strange errors if you overwrite a native global variable.